# How to match any number of capital letters?

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("CSE");
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

why is the obove code raising an java.lang.IllegalStateException ? How can i match any number of capital letters?

Comment: Does there have to be at least one capital. if so you need `+` rather than `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Matcher.find()` to initiate the regex matching process.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("CSE");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `matcher.matches();` before calling a `matcher.group());`

`matcher.group()` give you the substring identified by the previous match.

Your patten should be `[A-Z]+`  . This will print all matches of capital letter sequences

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("CSEsdsdWWERdfsdfSSEEfdD");

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```